# How to figure out Android parameters in INT?

Tags: android

Many Android methods to set layout aspects take an INT as parameter, but the description of those methods on the Google guides and documentation show as if the arguments were strings. For instance, the setOrientation() method of a LinearLayout. Here's the description:

> public void setOrientation (int orientation)
>
> Should the layout be a column or a row.
>
> android:orientation
>
> Parameters Pass HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL. Default value is HORIZONTAL.

As you can see, the method takes an INT as parameter, but the description tells me to pass either HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.

I noticed the same pattern on many other methods, so how do I figure out what values to pass to achieve what I want?

**Update**: By trial and error I found that 0 represents horizontal and 1 vertical. Shouldn't this documentation explain this more clearly, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because those are `static final int`s called `HORIZONTAL` and `VERTICAL` so you would call:

```
setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Gotcha. A heads up in the documentation would be nice though :)

Comment: It's there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#constants

Answer (score 1):

agreed, i wish google would have used enums instead of ints and took the slight, slight performance hit of doing so.

you can usually find the int constants defined in the docs for the class of the method you are looking at. for example, the javadocs for [LinearLayout's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) `setOrientation()` method mention `HORIZONTAL` and `VERTICAL`, and those constants can be found here,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#HORIZONTAL
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#VERTICAL

now, the fact that google doesn't link to the constants from the docs for `setOrientation()`, and that the docs for those constants are blank can't be excused.